# vue-select: selecting multiple options with same label

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-select

I have an options array with the same label but different value. But vue-select only allows one option to be selected.

```
 <v-select v-model="selectedData" multiple options="[{
        id:1,
        label: 'New York'
      }, {
        id:2,
        label : 'New York'
      }]">
```

As per the above snip, I want to select both the options but I am only able to select one of them.
I tried `reduce` prop based on `id`, but it only filtered the selected value.

How can it be achieved? ([reference](https://vue-select.org/))

https://codepen.io/aniket_777/pen/QWweZbE

Comment: Maybe `multiple = 'true'\'false'`?

Comment: giving just multiple prop is true by default and it is allowing to select mutilple options but not with same label.

Comment: seems that this is an open issue: https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/804

Comment: the options prop should be binded:

`` :options="[{
        id:1,
        label: 'New York'
      }, {
        id:2,
        label : 'New York'
      }, {
        id:3,
        label : 'Delhi'
      }]"``

Comment: Yes its is binded via Variable